# Detect if related list exceeds a specific number

Tags: apex, validation, flow, related-list, master-detail

I have two related objects example `Teacher` and `Student`. Inside my parent object `Teacher` I have a field `maximum_number_of_student`.What I want is that if I add a new `student` the code will check if I exceed the `maximum_number_of_student` of the parent object. If not, new student will be added else the system will give an error that the number of student exceed for the certain teacher. What is the best way to do it ? Please help. Thank you...

Comment: You might get away with Roll Up summary and a validation rule something like this `teacher__r.count_of_total_students__c > teacher__r.maximum_number_of_student__c`.

Answer (score 0):

I not sure if you have master detail relationship. But you can do this in trigger. Using inner query.

```
List<User> users = [SELECT Name, (SELECT id FROM Applications__r) FROM User];
for (User u : users) {
    // do something with it...
    u.Applications__r.size();
}
```

Alternatively, you can use an AggregateResult query which would query the child and group by the Id lookup.

```
// Assumes you have a Lookup called User__c
Map<Id, Integer> userAppCountMap = new Map<Id, Integer>();
for (AggregateResult aggRes : [
      SELECT COUNT(ID) numApps, User__c userId
      FROM Application__c
      GROUP BY User__c
]) {
    Id userId = (Id) aggRes.get('userId');
    Integer numApps = (Integer) aggRes.get('numApps');
    userAppCountMap.put(userId, numApps);
}
```